# Odd/even records have unique CSS class

Tags: bolt-cms

Using Bolt, I'd like to grab my 4 latest entries.  Easy enough.  However, I need the 1st and 3rd entries to have a specific CSS class around them while the 2nd and 4th entries would have their own class.

Ultimately the HTML should look something like:

```
    <div class="quarter alt">
        <h3><a href="{{ record.link }}">{{ record.title }}</a></h3>
        <p>{{ record.teaser }}</p>
        <p><a href="{{ record.link }}">Read more</a>.</p>  
    </div>
    <div class="quarter">
        <h3><a href="{{ record.link }}">{{ record.title }}</a></h3>
        <p>{{ record.teaser }}</p>
        <p><a href="{{ record.link }}">Read more</a>.</p>  
    </div>
    <div class="quarter alt">
        <h3><a href="{{ record.link }}">{{ record.title }}</a></h3>
        <p>{{ record.teaser }}</p>
        <p><a href="{{ record.link }}">Read more</a>.</p>  
    </div>
    <div class="quarter">
        <h3><a href="{{ record.link }}">{{ record.title }}</a></h3>
        <p>{{ record.teaser }}</p>
        <p><a href="{{ record.link }}">Read more</a>.</p>  
    </div>
```

I've played around with the snippets and documentation and am at the point where I found loop.first but of course that only works on the first entry:

```
{% setcontent records = "entries/latest/4" %}
{% for record in records %}

{% if loop.first %}
    <div class="quarter alt">
        <h3><a href="{{ record.link }}">{{ record.title }}</a></h3>
        <p>{{ record.teaser }}</p>
        <p><a href="{{ record.link }}">Read more</a>.</p>  
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div class="quarter">
        <h3><a href="{{ record.link }}">{{ record.title }}</a></h3>
        <p>{{ record.teaser }}</p>
        <p><a href="{{ record.link }}">Read more</a>.</p>  
    </div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any idea how I could edit my template to accomplish what I'm after?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the css [:nth-child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Example:

```
.quarter:nth-child(odd) {
    /* CSS for row 1 & 3 */
}

.quarter:nth-child(even) {
    /* CSS for row 2 & 4 */
}
```

(@ruffp, thanks for the feedback)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `loop.index` or `loop.index0` variable that twig uses in your loop

```
{% setcontent records = "entries/latest/4" %}
{% for record in records %}
    {% if loop.index is odd %}
        <div class="quarter">
            {{ loop.index }} odd stuff
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="quarter alt">
            {{ loop.index }} even stuff
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

For more info you can look at http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html and http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/odd.html